# How to choose which template to render based on a property

Tags: jsrender

I am trying to upgrade from the old jQuery tmpl to this awesome new jsRender.

My code is already working.

I am building a FORM with templates based on a JSON returned by the backend.

The object is:

```
var form = {
  name: "addNew",
  fields: [{type: "text", name: "Age"}, {type: "hidden", name: "Id"}] 
};
```

In the old jQuery plugin I did like this

```
'{{tmpl(this.data) selectInputTemplate( this.data )}}'
```

Where the function selectInputTemplate() will return the template name based on the field type.

How would this work in the new jsRender ?

---

EDIT:

How can I access the entire object ? In old jQuery Template was with *this.data*.

I created a helper function to return me the template, but I need to know how to access the entire object to send it to helper.

---

EDIT 2:

This is ugly but it is working:

```
var form_field_wrap =
    "{{if type === 1 tmpl='form_field_input_text' /}}" +
    "{{if type === 2 tmpl='form_field_input_select' /}}" +
    "{{if type === 3 tmpl='form_field_input_checkbox' /}}" +
    "{{if type === 4 tmpl='form_field_input_radios' /}}" +
    "";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template you can access the entire contextual data object, using `#data`.

(See [Paths and expressions](https://www.jsviews.com/#paths))

In a helper function, the `this` object is generally the current `view` object, so you can get the data object as [`this.data`](https://www.jsviews.com/#viewobject@data).

Here is an example that shows both the above methods:

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
    {{include tmpl=~getTmpl(#data)/}}
</script>

<div id="page"></div>

<script>
    var myTmpl = $.templates("#myTmpl"),
        data = { name: "Jo" },
        helpers = {
            getTmpl: function(data) {
                return $.templates("{{: 123}}" + data.name + this.data.name);
            }
        },
        html = myTmpl.render(data, helpers);
    $("#page").html(html);
</script>
```

Incidentally, you can write your example with `{{if}}` tags like this

```
"{{if type === 1 tmpl='form_field_input_text'}}" +
"{{else type === 2 tmpl='form_field_input_select'}}" +
"{{else type === 3 tmpl='form_field_input_checkbox'}}" +
"{{else type === 4 tmpl='form_field_input_radios'}}" +
"{{/if}}"
```

Comment: Does this work for you? (If so can you 'accept' the answer. Thanks...)

Comment: Yes it does ! Thank you s much ! jsRender is awesome !!! It gives a lot of power to my App. Now I ask you: Why would I need react or vue when I have this ? Just great !!! Thank you !!!

Comment: Thanks. Yes, JsRender together with data-binding ([JsViews](https://www.jsviews.com)) does constitute quite a powerful and extensive platform. Of course it is (unfortunately) not nearly as well known as React, Vue, etc.

See this for a comparison discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57322571/1054484